# How can I challenge a grade based on false accusation of submitting non-original work?

Tags: plagiarism, grades

I need some advice on what I can do, and how much hope is left on this case-

A couple of months back, I finished my Media GCSE and got a C. It's alright, I guess, but I hoped for a little higher. It turns out I got 2 points off a B. What dragged me down was my Horror Movie Trailer Coursework- I had to make a horror movie trailer.

I decided to do mine a bit differently- I made a basic engine in Unity and built a 3D Horror world around it. It was made out of assets made by me, including textures, code and I worked solo on it completely. It turned out great, and it wasn't the trailer itself that my teacher had a problem with. It was the fact that he didn't believe it was mine, and I got under half marks because of this.

The trailer was owned completely by me- I owned the textures, code, I did the editing- everything. But because it was made in Unity and the graphics were pretty well, my teacher wasn't buying that it was mine. There was quite a time frame before me submitting my work and getting the results back. I didn't think this problem would arise, so I deleted my work, and the project is gone due to a change in laptop. Now, I have no evidence of it.

I believe that the coursework was marked unfairly, but with no evidence of the coursework, and as I've already received the C, I'm not sure what I can do about it, but I really badly want that B.

Can I not bring it up with the school? Could I write a complaint letter or something? I just don't know what I can do- I'm a bit lost. I hope you can help me, and sorry if this is the wrong place. I was just disappointed in getting a C when I should have a B.

Comment: You didn't keep any of your original work? Backups? What if in the future you want to do something similar?

Comment: Without backups, I don't think that there is anything you can do - to be blunt: if you have no evidence, then you really do not have a case.

Comment: Most institutions have some sort of procedure for appealing charges of academic dishonesty.  You'll have to investigate what those procedures are at your specific institution.

Comment: Unfortunately, having deleted the work so promptly comes across as suspicious. You have a tough case ahead of you. Can you rebuild (at least part of) the trailer using the same tools as before, to at least demonstrate a proof-of-concept that you can create that project with original work?

Comment: I don't believe this to be an actual duplicate of the other question.  The answer here is that the asker is out of luck, because he kept no evidence.  My ex-wife had a similar situation years ago where I helped her edit a term paper and the prof refused to believe it was hers.  It was.  She had kept her hand-written rough drafts, some with my editing comments, that showed the evolution of the paper.  She won the case.  Deservedly so.  Having no history, no Git version control repository, of his source code, etc., this asker has NO case.  Accept the C and learn to use a version control system.